# Anyone know where I can download a zipped Python distribution?

Tags: python, download

Yeah, kind of random, but I was wondering if anyone could link me to a .zip file containing a Python distribution. I know I could download the installer, so please don't suggest that. :P.

Comment: Do you mean a zipped copy of the source or an installer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use the official [Source Distribution](http://python.org/ftp/python/3.1.1/Python-3.1.1.tar.bz2) of Python? It is not zipped, but you can unpack the whole thing in one line of Python.

```
import tarfile; tarfile.open('Python-3.1.1.tar.bz2').extractall()
```

Comment: Nice! but Its like CD Driver is in CD

Answer (score 4):

I didn't exactly understand what you want. Is [Portable Python](http://portablepython.com/) enough for you? If it isn't, check Python's [official download](http://python.org/download/) website where you have a lot of options - including compressed source tarballs. You can downlod the tarballs, extract and create a zip file.